# Mongodb splitting aggregation result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm currently trying to split an aggregation result in two differents arrays using only mongodb.

My main goal is to create two subset of user with the same distribution regarding the number of interactions that they have made. For this I'm currently making this request:

```
db.getCollection('Interaction').aggregate([
 { $group : { _id : "$userId", count: { $sum: 1 }}},
 { $sort : { count : -1 }},
 { $group : { _id :{$mod : [_rand() * 2, 2]}, ids : { $push: "$_id"}}}   
}
```

My main issue actualy is that the [_rand()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rand/) function is called only once during the aggregation execution to I only have all my result in a single array.

Also, a random distribution is not so good. Is there a way to use the index of each result ?

## Edit 1 :

After @dnickless answer I still got an issue on distribution in the groupBy part. Ideally I would like to do something like this

```
db.getCollection('Interaction').aggregate([
        { $group : { _id : "$userId", count: { $sum: 1 }}},
        { $sort : { count : -1 }},
        { $bucket: {
                groupBy: { $mod: [ { $indexOfArray : ??? }, 2 ] },
                boundaries: [ 0, 1 ],
                default: 2,
                output: {
                  "users": { $push: "$_id"}
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    { allowDiskUse: true })
```

That could split even index and odd index into two separated array. But I would like to apply the `$indexOfArray` on the current aggregation result.

To give you more context here is my Interaction object model :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5af01..."), "name" : "WATCH", "date" : ISODate("2018-05-07T09:32:53.219Z") }
```

Without the bucket part I have this result :

```
{ "_id" : "5b1e7f...", "count" : 43.0 } 
{ "_id" : "5b1e75...", "count" : 41.0 } 
{ "_id" : "5b1e7a...", "count" : 40.0 }
...
```

I would like my answer to look like this :

```
{
  { "_id" : 0, "users" : [ "5b1e7f...", "5b1e7a...", ... ] }, // even index results
  { "_id" : 1, "users" : [ "5b1e75...", ... ] }  // odd index results
}
```

My end goal is to split my users in 2 groups with evenly distributed numbers of interactions.

## Edit 2 :

Finally found a solution to resolve my problem :

```
db.getCollection('Interaction').aggregate([
        { $group : { _id : "$userId", count: { $sum: 1 }}},
        { $sort : { count : -1 }},
        { $group : { _id : "whatever" , user : { $push : { _id : "$_id" , count : "$count"}}}},
        { $unwind : { path : "$user" , "includeArrayIndex" : "rank"}},
        { $bucket: {
                groupBy: { $mod: [ "$rank"  , 2 ] },
                boundaries: [ 0, 1 ],
                default: 2,
                output: {
                  "users": { $push: "$user._id"}
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    { allowDiskUse: true })
```

Probably not the most optimized solution at all, but still do the job :)
If you have any advise to improve it I'm still interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fuly understand what exactly you are trying to achieve here without seeing some sample input and output. However, have you tried using [$bucketAuto](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucketAuto/)? Something like this:

```
db.getCollection('Interaction').aggregate([
 { $group : { _id : "$userId", count: { $sum: 1 }}},
 { $bucketAuto : {
     groupBy : "$count",
     buckets : 2, // number of buckets goes here
     output : {
       ids : { $push : "$id" }
     }
   }
 }])
```

If you want to go more sophisticated regarding the distribution aspect you could perhaps try something like this which would throw all even counts into one pot and all odd ones into another:

```
$bucket: {
    groupBy: { $mod: [ "$count", 2 ] },
    boundaries: [ 0, 1 ],
    default: 2,
    output: {
      "docs": { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
}
```

Depending on the type of your `userId` field you could perhaps come up with a more "random" distribution.

Lastly, I am not sure what exactly you mean by

> "Is there a way to use the index of each result ?"

Perhaps something like [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/), [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) and/or [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/)...?

Alternatively, you could perhaps try to [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) the sorted array into two equally sized parts (using [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/)d by 2), then [$reverseArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray/) one of them and then [$zip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) both arrays up again which should result in something like when you shuffle a deck of playing cards. After that, you would need to flatten the nested array into a single one again (using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) and [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) or so) and then slice the array again in two parts which should be what you are looking for if I am not too tired by now to think through the statistical parts here.

Comment: Hey, thank's for your answer, I edited my question with more details, and a new problem reguarding the `groupBy` expression.